# Achartengine : reverse plot

Tags: android, achartengine

I'm using achartengine in my Android Application, it works well but i have a question.

Is it possible to reverse plot?

I mean in my graph, new values which are added to my XY series with the function add, are added at end of the series, and then the graph is redrawn, so new values appears at right of the graph.

But i want to add my new value at index 0, in order to show on the graph only the last X values.

[image]

Sorry if it's not very clear

Thanks

Comment: Surely you just need to be adding your data to index 0 within the XY series? It seems like that should solve your problem, as the data will get plotted in the order that it appears in the series

Comment: There is no method to add a value at a specific index: the only method to add data for the XYSeries is add(value x, value y). Add(0, value y) only erase data at value x = 0 and plot new data, in can't increment others x index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i've found a trick:

Dataset is my XYseries and mRenderer my multipleSeriesRenderer

- I've changed alignment of the Y axis:

> mRenderer.setYAxisAlign(Align.RIGHT, 0);

- I've erased automatic labels:

> mRenderer.setXLabels(0);

- The 0 on the axe X is now a custom label, so every time a new value is added to the graph, I have to change is position:

> mRenderer.setXAxisMax(dataset.getItemCount() - 1); mRenderer.addXTextLabel(dataset.getItemCount() - 1, "0");

- And to finish, i change the X axis min everytime a new value is added, in order to get a fix scale:

> mRenderer.setXAxisMin(dataset.getItemCount() - scale - 1);

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for inserting data to `XYSeries` at a given index. However you could get to this behavior by clearing the current data and adding it back, with the new value included. I know this would not be a very optimal way, but it helps you get to your needed behavior.

**Edit**: I added an `add(index, x, y)` method in `XYSeries`. You can download a version including this feature [here](https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/org/achartengine/achartengine/1.1.0/).

Comment: Ok, thanks Dan. I'm going to find a solution, i'll post my answer later.

Comment: Don't seems to work. Or I don't know how it works ^^, new values are plotted at the end. Even if I add a new value at index 0: add(0, valueX1 = 1, 2.5), if I add another value later: add(0, valueX2 = 2, 3.5) => valueX2>valueX1, so valueX2 is plotted at the right of valueX1. What I need to do is add(0, valueX = 0, valueY) to plot the new point, and change valueX of the other points by valueX + 1, i'm not sure it's possible. Thank you for your help Dan